# Use mechanize to log into megaupload

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize

I am attempting to use the following code to log into megaupload. My question is, how do i that it successfully logged in? I print out the current URL at the end of the code, but when i run the script it just returns www.megaupload.com.

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('http://www.megaupload.com/?c=login')

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form('loginfrm')

#User credentials
br.form['username'] = 'USERNAMEGOESHERE'
br.form['password'] = 'PASSWORDGOESHERE'

br.submit()


#prints out the current log in
print br.geturl()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search the error message in the response body:

```
"Username and password do not match" in br.response().read()
```

Or check if you got the expected cookie (simple example, tweak as needed):

```
any(c.domain == ".megaupload.com" and c.name == "user" for c in cj)
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually was able to check for "Welcome USERNAME". I attempted to upvote you but I am a new user and i require "15 reputation" before I can do so.

Comment: @user520574, you cannot select it as answer either? well, never mind.

Comment: I was able to select it as the answer, I didn't see that option before. Thanks again.