# Login with python - megaupload

Tags: python, authentication

I'm trying to fix a program which can login to my MU account and retrieve some data....

I don't know what am I doing wrong....That's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('http://megaupload.com/index.php?c=login', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.megaupload.com/index.php?c=filemanager')
print resp.read()
```

Thx for any answer!

Comment: What's the error they give back? Also, have you tried setting user-agent?

Comment: there is no error! It just prints again the login page :(

Comment: Did you check the HTTP parameter, so you simulate a browser user-agent etc. and not something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate the filling of the form.

For that you can use [mechanize lib](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) base on perl module WWW::Mechanize.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, mechanize

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6')]

br.open('http://www.megaupload.com/?c=login')
br.select_form('loginfrm')

br.form['username'] = username
br.form['password'] = password

br.submit()

resp = br.open('http://www.megaupload.com/index.php?c=filemanager')

print resp.read()
```

See [Use mechanize to log into megaupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422389/use-mechanize-to-log-into-megaupload)

Answer (score 2):

Okay I just implemented it myself and it seems you just forgot one value - that's why I always use TamperData or something similar to just check what my browser is sending to the server - WAY easier and shorter than going through the HTML.

Anyways just add 'redir' : 1 to your dict and it'll work:

```
import http.cookiejar
import urllib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password, 'login' : 1, 'redir' : 1})
    response = opener.open("http://www.megaupload.com/?c=login", login_data)
    with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(response.read().decode("UTF-8")) #so we can compare resulting html easily
```

Although I must say I'll have a look at mechanize and co now - I do something like that often enough that it could be quite worthwhile. Although I can't stress enough that the most important help is still a browser plugin that lets you check the sent data ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) which are designed to streamline these kinds of processes. Otherwise, I think your opener is missing at least one important component: something to process cookies. Here's a bit of code I have laying around from the last time I did this:

```
# build opener with HTTPCookieProcessor
cookie_jar = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('tasks.cookies')
o = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)
)
```

Comment: "Otherwise, I think your opener is missing at least one important component: something to process cookies." Wouldn't the CookieJar handle that just fine? Why would he need anything special?

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but I think when I was last doing this I saw the Mozilla-style cookie jar suggested because it did a better job with storing credentials.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to add the `c=login` name/value pair to login_data rather than including it dorectly on the URL.

You're probably also breaking a TOS/EULA, but I can't say I care that much.

Comment: Terms of Service / End User Licence Agreement.  It probably says somewhere on the website that you aren't supposed to do what you're doing.