# Download from Megaupload with login - Python

Tags: python, authentication, download, megaupload

It's my first question here.
Today, I've done a little application using wxPython: a simple Megaupload Downloader, but yet, it doesn't support premium accounts.
Now I would like to know how to download from MU with a login (free or premium user).

I'm very new to Python, so please don't be specific and "professional".
I used to download files with *urlretrieve* but, but is there a way to pass "arguments" or something to be able to log in as a premium user ?
Thank you. :D

EDIT =

News: new help needed xD

After trying with PyCUrl, htmllib2 and mechanize, I've done the login with urllib2 and cookiejar (the requested html says the username).

But when I start download a file, surely the server doesn't keep my login, in fact the downloaded file seems corrupted (I changed wait time from 45 to 25 seconds).

How can I download a file from MegaUpload keeping my previously done login? Thanks for your patient :D

Comment: See [login with python - megaupload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134250/login-with-python-megaupload) and [use mechanize to log into megaupload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422389/use-mechanize-to-log-into-megaupload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like this are usually frowned upon, they are very broad, and there are already an abundance of answers if you just search on google.

You can use urllib, or mechanize, or any library you can make an http post request with.
megaupload looks to have the form values

```
login:1
redir:1
username:
password:
```

just post those values at `http://megaupload.com/?c=login`

all you should have to do is set your `username` and `password` to the correct values!

Comment: Thanks a lot :D And how can i mantain these values throught 2 different pages?

Comment: @Allesandro the server saves your ip adress, that's why can also log in with a browser and you are still logged in after changing the site

Answer (score 1):

For logging in using Python follow the following steps.

1. Find the list of parameters to be sent in the POST request and the url where the request has to be made by viewing the source of the login form. You may use a browser with "Inspect Element" feature to find it easily. [parameter name examples - userid, password]. Just check the  tags name attribute.
2. Most of the sites set a cookie on logging in and the cookie has to be sent along with subsequent requests. To handle this download httllib2 (http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/ ) and read the wiki page on the link given. It has shown how to login with examples.
3. Now you can make subsequent requests for files, the cookies etc. will be handled automatically by httplib2.

Comment: Ehm, I am sorry but your link seems to be a 404 page :D Sorry :D

Comment: oh..google code was in maintenance mode this evening. The link is correct (I downloaded and used it from here :) ). Try downloading after a few hours or just search for httplib2 alternate download locations

Comment: I'm unlucky :D on the net there are some guides (maybe in italian -my language-) to httplib2? I started some days ago coding with Python but i'm loving it :D

Answer (score 1):

i do alot of web stuff with python, i perfer using pycurl you can get it [here](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/)

it is very simple to post data and login with curl, i've used it accross many languages such as PHP, python, and C++, hope this helps

Comment: "To sum up, PycURL is very fast (esp. for multiple concurrent operations) and very feature complete, but has a somewhat complex interface." Sure that it fits with me? :D

Comment: well if you look at some examples, you can see it's quite simple. but it what ever floats ur boat, i've just always used curl for just about all my web projects. i hope you find something that fits you =]

Comment: Thanks for your help :D oh, it isn't compatible with python 2.7... :( xD

Comment: well (assuming ur running windows) they only have a installer for i believe 2.1-2.5 (or something like that) you could always install it from source, but it is a pain on windows. if ur running linux some distro's come with pycurl pre-installed, and if not it's very simple to install. you could try googling around to see if someone has a pre-built installer for 2.7, and pycurl is compatible with 2.7, just those installers where built with python version 2.1-2.5, i'm currently running python 2.7 with pycurl support, hope you can find a solution =D

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib [this](https://github.com/nikod/guicavane/blob/master/guicavane/Accounts/Megaupload.py) is a good example

Comment: This is a very exausthive example, but a little bit too much difficult for me xD